# Refresh a view in UINavigationController Stack

Tags: ios, ios5, uinavigationcontroller

I am currently building my view in the viewDidLoad method, it adds various buttons that links through to another view. The issue I am having is that when a user clicks on a button and goes through to the other view they can purchase an IAP, then when the user clicks on the back button I would like the view to 'refresh' to show that this purchase has now become active.

How do I refresh the view?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe `viewWillAppear` ?

Comment: this just seems to build my view on top of the previous view, so I get double?

Comment: On the viewWillAppear method simply run the method that checks if the purchase has been made so the button's text is changed. How are you checking to verify a purchase has been made?

Answer (score 0):

any view can be explicitly refreshed by calling `setNeedsDisplay` on that view.
Further you should not mix up the terms `UIViewController` with `UIView`.
I asume you dont have a refresh problem, that you would only have in self programmed custom views. I excpect that the data of the related views was not updated.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I have called this method in the viewWill appear method like so: [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

Comment: i think one of your subviews needs the refresh. it makes no sense to call needsDisplay in viewWillAppear. but i think your problem is not caused by a refresh issue, maybe your data is not updated.

Comment: I have ensured that my data is refreshing in viewWillAppear. Basically I need to now refresh the button views so that instead of buy it displays watch. How would I go about refreshing the subviews?

Comment: before adding the subviews, store them in a property or field, then you can access and refresh them whenever you want. anotherway asign a view.tag = 101 . each sub view a different tag, then you can get a subView by tag, and refresh it

Comment: Ok, this does make sense, however, where am I putting this code, currently I have it the viewDidLoad method which obviously gets called when the view is first loaded, if I put all my code in the viewWillAppear method it keeps the original views but adds a new set on top which logically does make sense but in this situation its driving me mad, I appreciate your help and patience with this.

Comment: in viewDidLoad, you shoudl create your UI  elemenst and Views. There you assign it to a field _myButtonView = UIButtonView alloc] initWithFrame: bla bla; then self.view addSubViews: _myButtonView; later you cann acees _mybUttonView.setneedsDisplay();; read some Apple demo code.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. Either store whether the purchase was made and then run the method that checks if a purchase was made in the viewWillAppear method of the view you are wishing to change

Or...
Setup a delegate callback that changes the button when a change is made on the purchase page (http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-custom-delegates/)

Or...
Manipluate the previous view directly by accessing it from the navigationController stack ([[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:YOURVIEW])

Answer (score 0):

build view in `viewDidLoad` so you add controls only once, but refresh in `viewWillShow`. Keep in mind, `viewWillShow` will refresh it right after the build is done by `viewDidLoad`. So keep values that define your controls appearance on the 1st `viewController`, say, in delegate mutable array

e.g. create and initiate an `NSMutableArray` in your `AppDelegate.h` and .m

in .h interface

```
NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

add property

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *yourArray;
```

in .m

```
@synthesyze yourArray;
```

initiate it in .m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

yourArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//add initial objects to it as many as you have controls
}
```

in the 1st `viewController`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

-(void)viewWillShow:(BOOL)animated{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//pull objects from array and apply to your controls, say you have a string as a 1st obj

NSString *tmpStr=[appDelegate.yourArray objectAtIndex:0];//use it some where, say button's title

//etc
}
```

you will change those values in the second `viewController` according to users choices

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

somewhere in 2nd `viewController` code update values in yourArray say on a

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//run a loop and update all objects

[appDelegate.yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:newObj];
}
```

and when you go back to 1st `viewController`, `viewWillShow` will refresh them from your delegate array.